# Jenkins Config File Maven Multiple Nexus Repositories Download

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies, nexus

So I want to setup a config file in Jenkins for a Maven project to use multiple repositories. The whole idea is to try and download from one if it cannot be found then download from the second one. Below is what I have configured now and from the Jenkins logs, I can see it 'downloading' from both repositories.

The problem is that it doesn't actually fallback if it can't find it in the first one it simply fails so something is wrong. I have to add that everything works fine if I use either of them exclusively so it's not a connectivity issue are anything else like that. Please help I have been at this for a day and a half now and I am fairly sure it's because I can't wrap my mind around the Maven Documentation.

```
[INFO] Downloading: https:NEW_NEXUS/artifact/1.15.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: http:OLD_NEXUS/artifact/1.15.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO]                   



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 

    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

        <mirrors>
            <mirror>
                <id>new-nexus</id>
                <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
                <name>New Nexus Repository</name>
                <url>NEW_NEXUS/nexus/repository/maven-public/</url>
            </mirror>  

            <mirror>
                <id>old-nexus</id>
                <mirrorOf>old-nexus</mirrorOf>
                <name>Old Nexus Repository</name>
                <url>OLD_NEXUS/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            </mirror>

        </mirrors>

        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>new-nexus</id>
                <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>central</id>
                        <url>http://central</url>
                        <releases>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </repository>

                    <repository>   
                        <id>old-nexus</id>
                        <name>Old Nexus Repository</name>
                        <url>OLD_NEXUS/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
                    </repository>

                </repositories>
                <pluginRepositories>
                    <pluginRepository>
                        <id>central</id>
                        <url>http://central</url>
                        <releases>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </releases>
                        <snapshots>
                            <enabled>true</enabled>
                        </snapshots>
                    </pluginRepository>
                </pluginRepositories>
            </profile>              
        </profiles>

        <activeProfiles>
            <activeProfile>new-nexus</activeProfile>        
        </activeProfiles>

    </settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using

```
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
```

you set the repository as mirror of *everything*, so every request is redirected to the `NEW_NEXUS/nexus/repository/maven-public` repository.

What you usually do:

Go into the Nexus as administrator and define a *repository group* which contains both repositories. Then just use this repository group as mirror of everything. The Nexus repository group behaves as you expect: It goes through all the repositories until it finds the requested artifact.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. The 2 Nexuses involved are different in the sense of one is 2.0.6 and the other is 3.3.1 they are also hosted on 2 different corporate environments and they are not able to talk to each other. At least at the moment. I am not really a devops guy so that's why I am learning as I go along

Comment: I tried this as well <mirror>
            <id>new-nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>!old-nexus,*</mirrorOf> and it still doesn't work

Comment: Does your Jenkins not know which of the two Nexus is reachable and which is not?

Comment: Jenkins can reach both of them. I am just not getting it right when it comes to configuring it to try and fetch dependency from one and then if not found then try from the other. I mean I can actually see it saying downloading from both of them yet throws not found exception when a jar is only on one of them instead of doing the smart thing. Apologies if I am not being clear enough I am just still learning and getting ever more frustrated.